# Uniform cover of the symmetric group by "multiples" of its subset

Tags: permutations, permutation-groups, packing-and-covering

Given a subset $T$ of the symmetric group $S_n$. For $p\in S_n$, define
$$pT = \{ pt\mid t\in T\}.$$

Questions:

> Q1: Is there a simple characterization of all subsets $\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}\subseteq S_n$ such that $p_1T,\dots, p_kT$ uniformly cover $S_n$? (i.e., every element of $S_n$ must be present in $p_1T, \dots, p_kT$ the same number of times)

> Q2: How to find a minimal set such set $\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}$? It is clear that $k\geq \frac{n!}{\gcd(n!,|T|)}$ -- is this lower bound achievable for any $T$?

> Q3: Given $m$ subsets $T_1, \dots, T_m$, how to uniformly cover $S_n$ by each of them with the same $\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}$?